# JBoss EAP 6.1: unable to update system properties with write-attribute operation

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x

Having the following system property:

```
<system-properties>
    <property name="foo" value="test1"/>
</system-properties>
```

I want to change its value to "test2" using Management API. In JBoss 7.1.1 this could be achieved with the following command:

```
/system-property=foo:write-attribute(name="value" value="test2")
```

In EAP 6.1 however, the same command results in:

```
{
    "outcome" => "failed",
    "failure-description" => "JBAS014792: Unknown attribute test2",
    "rolled-back" => true
}
```

The only way I can use write-attribute for system property seems to be:

```
/system-property=foo:write-attribute(name="value")
{"outcome" => "success"}
```

which effectively unsets value of the property:

```
<system-properties>
    <property name="foo"/>
</system-properties>
```

I there any other way to update value of system property in EAP 6.1?

Comment: I think it's a bug. Instead of changing the system property try to delete and add it again.

Comment: Does the property already exist? If it does exist, `write-attribute` should work. If not you need to use `add`.

Comment: Yes, property already exists. Also, for related EAP 6.1 add/remove problem, please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20156031/jboss-eap-6-1-management-api-system-property-not-seen-after-remove-followed-by